# jquery ajax post goes to the wrong action method in MVC 4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

Here is my view

```
 <div>
    @using ( Html.BeginForm("jQueryPost", "Home",null, FormMethod.Post, new { id="FormPost" }))
    { 
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x=> x.Name)<br />
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.LastName)<br />
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Age)
    <input type=submit value="submit" />
    }
</div>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#FormPost').submit(function (e) {
            //This line will prevent the form from submitting
            e.preventDefault();
            alert('ajax post here');

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: $('FormPost').attr('action'),
                data: $('FormPost').serialize(),
                accept: 'application/json',
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    alert('error: ' + xhr.statusText);
                },
                success: function (response) {
                    alert('resp: ' + response.data);
                }
            });
        });


    });

 </script>
```

These are the Home controller's methods:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}


[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public JsonResult jQueryPost(IndexVM vm)
{
    IndexVM _vm = vm;
    return Json("name posted was: " + _vm.Name);

}
```

This is the route map

```
 routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

When the page loads it goes to the Index action method, which is understandable. However, when I submit the form it is going to the Index action method again. Why is that?

The alert message 'ajax post here' gets shown followed by the success alert ('resp: ' + response.data). However since I am not returning anything in the Index I get a resp: undefined in the alert box.

How do I fix this so that the form post goes to the `public JsonResult jQueryPost(IndexVM vm)` method? I also tried replacing the JsonResult to ActionResult and it fared the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot the `#` in you jQuery selectors:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: $('#FormPost').attr('action'),
    data: $('#FormPost').serialize(),
    accept: 'application/json',
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        alert('error: ' + xhr.statusText);
    },
    success: function (response) {
        alert('resp: ' + response.data);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. That worked. I can't accept the answer for another 5 minutes. Will do that soon.